# Forward-chaining beneath first search in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, stack-overflow

i'm trying to find the problem in fugiring out the stack over flow problem 
the alogrithm is clear but it and the recursive call is made in an if satetment so i can't figure out why is it going bad

```
(defparameter BF '(B C) )
(defparameter BR '((R1(B D E) F )(R2( D G) A )(R3(C F) A )(R4(C) D)
                     (R5(D ) E )(R6(A) H ) (R7(B ) X) (R8(X C) A ) ))
(defun chain_av (BF BR F)
(loop 
    (unless (member F BF)
      (dolist (R  BR)
        (when (actionable  R BF)
          (remove R BR)
          (append BF (conclusion-part R)))
      (if (member F BF) (return "yes")
        (or(chain_av BF BR F) (return nil)))))))


(defun conclusion-part( r)
(caddr r)
)
(write (chain_av BF BR 'H ))
    (defun actionable (r facts)
        (let ((ok t))
            (dolist (p (cadr r) ok)
                (if (not (member p facts))
                    (setq ok nil)))
                ok))
```

and i'm still not sure if it's really beneath first search 
and should'i prove that by having a variable that keeps track of the elements that it when by
and thanks in advance

Comment: to ask a question you need to post formatted code. Your code is not formatted. Second: you need a description of the error and the code you used, which causes this error and a reproducible way.

Comment: The code uses free variables: maybe there was a problem when renaming variables for this question (e.g. "but" should be "F"?). What is `part_conclusion`? Should `BF` be `*BF*`?

Comment: the stars have nothing to do and part-conclusion is missing an R

Comment: i'm trying to make a inference engine algorthim and the rules A and B => C are represented by (R1 ( A B) C) ( it's a valid way to represent rules in a rule based expert system )

Comment: `append` returns a new list; it doesn't modify any of its arguments. If a Lisp program calls `append` such that the return value is ignored, that call is useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some general remarks about some mistakes in your code, followed by hints about how to implement forward chaining.

### Code formatting

It is important you format your code properly, otherwise you or your peers won't be able to read it back easily. See for example https://lisp-lang.org/style-guide/:

```
(defun conclusion-part( r)
(caddr r)
)
```

The above has parentheses on their own lines, which is very not idiomatic. Also, Common Lisp has a function named `THIRD` that is easier to understand than `CADDR` for most people. Indent properly and put parentheses at the end. Use an editor like Emacs which can indent the code automatically: that helps identifying cases where what you write is different from what you intended to write, because auto-indentation follows the list structure and can help spot misplaced parentheses.

```
(defun conclusion-part (rule)
  (third rule))
```

### Accessor functions

What you did good is to define a `conclusion-part` accessor function to access part of your *rule* ad-hoc data structure. Having a distinct set of accessors that are not tied to a specific implementation helps, and is a good opportunity to introduce meaningful names. You should do the same for all parts of the rule (you use CADR directly elsewhere, which is not as clean).

For example (feel free to find better names):

```
(defun rule-name (rule) (first rule))
(defun rule-antecedent (rule) (second rule))
(defun rule-consequent (rule) (cddr rule))
```

Notice that `rule-consequent` is my rewrite of `conclusion-part`, except it always returns a list with a single element (can you see why?). This is useful later when you call `append`, and it is consistent with `rule-antecedent` which returns a list.

### Actionability of rules

Functions that return either true or false are called predicates and are by convention suffixed with `-p` in Lisp (and `-?` in Scheme). You may or may not follow that rule, but please introduce more meaningful variable names. Here is how you could rewrite it:

```
(defun actionablep (rule facts)
  (dolist (term (rule-antecedent rule) t)
    (unless (member term facts)
      (return nil))))
```

Since you already know `loop`, you could also write:

```
(defun actionablep (rule facts)
  (loop
    :for term :in (rule-antecedent rule)
    :always (member term facts)))
```

### Forward chaining

There are some problems here too:

- you do not use the return value of [`REMOVE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) or [`APPEND`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm), which are functions that are guaranteed to not mutate their arguments (unlike `DELETE` and `NCONC`, and even for those functions only the returned value matters, the ability that is granted to mutate the existing storage is implementation-defined and only there to allow efficient reuse of memory).
- In some branch you want to return `"yes"`, in another `nil`; CL might be dynamically typed, but there is no need for a string return value here.
- A `return` form only exist the innermost `nil` block. In your case that means you return from the implicit block established by [`DOLIST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dolist.htm), not the one from the [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm). You could name your `loop` but this is in fact not necessary here, you can write the whole thing without `return`. More generally, you can have a purely functional approach.

### Hint

I wrote a `forward-chaining` function, and traced it; in the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (trace forward-chaining)
```

Here is how I tested my implementation:

```
(forward-chaining '(B C)
                  '((R1 (B D E) F)
                    (R2 (D G) A)
                    (R3 (C F) A)
                    (R4 (C) D)
                    (R5 (D) E)
                    (R6 (A) H)
                    (R7 (B) X)
                    (R8 (X C) A))
                  'H)
```

I am testing the code with SBCL, the actual output might differ in your Lisp implementation:

```
  0: (FORWARD-CHAINING (B C) ((R1 (B D E) F) (R2 (D G) A) (R3 (C F) A) (R4 (C) D) (R5 (D) E) (R6 (A) H) (R7 (B) X) (R8 (X C) A)) H)
    1: (FORWARD-CHAINING (B C D) ((R1 (B D E) F) (R2 (D G) A) (R3 (C F) A) (R5 (D) E) (R6 (A) H) (R7 (B) X) (R8 (X C) A)) H)
      2: (FORWARD-CHAINING (B C D E) ((R1 (B D E) F) (R2 (D G) A) (R3 (C F) A) (R6 (A) H) (R7 (B) X) (R8 (X C) A)) H)
        3: (FORWARD-CHAINING (B C D E F) ((R2 (D G) A) (R3 (C F) A) (R6 (A) H) (R7 (B) X) (R8 (X C) A)) H)
          4: (FORWARD-CHAINING (B C D E F A) ((R2 (D G) A) (R6 (A) H) (R7 (B) X) (R8 (X C) A)) H)
            5: (FORWARD-CHAINING (B C D E F A H) ((R2 (D G) A) (R7 (B) X) (R8 (X C) A)) H)
            5: FORWARD-CHAINING returned (H)
          4: FORWARD-CHAINING returned (H)
        3: FORWARD-CHAINING returned (H)
      2: FORWARD-CHAINING returned (H)
    1: FORWARD-CHAINING returned (H)
  0: FORWARD-CHAINING returned (H)
```

The basic structure of the program is:

```
(defun forward-chaining (rules facts goal)
  (or ...
      (loop 
        for ... in ...
        thereis (and (actionablep ... ...)
                     (forward-chaining ... ... ...)))))
```

In other words: either the goal is already a known fact, or there is an actionable rule by which goal is transitively reachable. Note that you might have an infinite recursion if your rules are non-terminating.

The order by which you visit rules determines if your strategy is depth-first (always follow the last tried rule and progress from that one, using the list of rules as a stack), or breadth-first (apply all activable rules for a given fact, using the list of rules as a queue). I don't know where the term "beneath"-first search comes from, I found no serious reference from it (there is one paper that references *Leiserson & Schardl 2010* when talking about *beneath* first search, but the [referenced article](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS433-CS9624/Resources/Leiserson-Schardl-2010.pdf) has no mention of it, only *breadth-first*, which is well-known).

Comment: can'u give me a hint how can'i guess the type of the search ( depth first or beneath first search ) and if i happen to formulate the code so it falls in one of these cases how can' i proove that ( is the code you tested depth first or beneath first )?

Comment: No that you say it, I think my example is depth-first, I start from one fact and follow rules recursively before trying other rules at the same level of search. For breadth-first search, I guess that means all actionable rules at a given search level should be applied and the resulting facts appended at the end of the current facts, before entering the next fixpoint loop. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I think that ,inorder to simulate the breadth-first search u need to go though the collected-factes and for each rule test if the goal exists in the facts base after activation it and empty the queue when you leave each level and so you can call the main function recursively with the updaed facts-base ( = facts + new-facts)

Comment: cam anyone ell m what i the difference between  depth first or bemath first ?